# WooCommerce auto state and city selection on entering pincode

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, postal-code, pin-code

In my WooCommerce store, I want the customer to just fill in their shipping pincode on checkout and the state and city fields should be filled automatically.

I tried google address auto complete but that fills in all the address fields. I just want to fill in the city and state from postcode.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you talking about ZIP Code in the US? Pin usually means a person identification number, e.g., for an ATM or to unlock a phone.

Comment: Yes I mean a Zip code or area postal code. In India pincode is Postal Index Number Code.

Comment: This question is way too broad for Stack Overflow. I would look into this plugin extension to see if it meets your needs. https://woocommerce.com/document/address-auto-complete-for-woocommerce/ or hire a developer to do this for you.

Comment: This is the plugin I tried, it fills in all the address fields while I specifically want only state and city selected automatically.

Comment: have you found a solution? I'm too eager to know